# Android Eclipse emulator: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to run the android emulator from eclipse using the ADT package from developer.android.com

When I press 'run' in eclipse, the virtual device opens (a black window with some 'buttons' on the right side), and then nothing more happens.

Here is the output from the console: https://gist.github.com/hansnn/5849335
The topic of this question is part of the console output and what I think is the problem.

I have googled to no avail, and I've tried pressing f5 (as suggested somewhere)

I've also tried restarting the adb daemon and running adb install -r myapp.apk. This returned: can't find 'MyFirstApplication.apk' to install.

How can I troubleshoot/fix this? Why do I get no output on the virtual device?
I think a lot of people are wondering this, as none of the threads I found on google were answered.

Comment: Does this happen with all AVD's or just one AVD with specific Configuration.?

Comment: Yes. I just tried it with a different AVD and did not see the expected output. However this AVD did look and behave as a phone (as opposed to a black screen).

Answer (score 0):

I've also been to such blackouts @ emulator.
Please try re-installing all(download the whole android package from the developers site)
or
Make an another account in your PC and try to run there(sometimes this helps)

In my case after downloading the the android package from developers.android.com
no such issues were observed give it a try.

Comment: re-installing the ADT package worked! Like Santhosh suggested, it was also a problem with my first AVD as it still does not work. I still experience some errors and the whole process is sort of buggy, but it works and I can test my apps! Thanks.